# How to use STDIN when ARGF was used?

Tags: ruby, io, stdin

I want to create a script, that I can pipe a list into: `cat list | ruby script.rb` I know that I can do this by using `ARGF` and it works. But then again I want to iterate over every line and do some action on it based on a decision. But when I use `STDIN.gets` I wont even be asked for input when I piped something in.

This is what I have right now

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8

items = []

ARGF.each_with_index do |line, index|
  items << line
end

items.each_with_index do |item, index|
  puts "What to do with #{item}? (1,2,3)"
  case STDIN.gets
  when 1
    puts "one"
  when 2
    puts "two"
  when 3
    puts "three"
  end
end
```

Thanks for any hints that point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading and browsing the Ruby-Docs for a while I found a way. I need to open a new IO-Stream, since `ARGF` is closed as cam pointed out.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

ARGF.each_with_index do |line, index|
  puts "#{index}: #{line}"
end

fd = IO.sysopen("/dev/tty", "w+")
IO.open(fd, "w+") do |io|
  puts "Enter something:"
  puts "You entered: #{io.gets}"
end
```

Propably not best-practice, but works for me right now and shall not be topic of this thread  .

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `ARGF` if you want to be able to use STDIN too.  STDIN is just the list of files and then it is closed (it is your shell doing this, not ruby, so you have no control).

Answer (score -1):

if list is a file name and its contain number of line which you want to use in your script then please try to run you script.rb which following command.

```
ruby script.rb list
```

note: list should be a file in which you have number lines for which you suppose to ask option. Also, please share you output after it!!!

Comment: Well I don't want it to make a difference if called `ruby script.rb item1 item2 itemN` or `cat somefile.txt | ruby script.rb` or `ruby script.rb < somefile.txt` or whatever. Or what are you trying to say?

Comment: Sorry, I cant go that much deep inside it right now but related to your question try all command with putting "puts ARGF.to_io.inspect" in script. It will return FILE object for "ruby script.rb somefile.txt" and it will return IO object for other command(somefile.txt | ruby script.rb or ruby script.rb < somefile.txt)